# Adobe Commerce Onboarding Showing All of a Sudden

Tags: magento2

All of a sudden I have this adobe commerce onboarding with a blue graduation hat icon in the lower left of my magento 2 admin. I've been running this magento platform for at least 7 years and it's just showing up now all of a sudden. How do I disable that? Anyone know by chance?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Admin Usage -> Enable Admin Usage Tracking -> Select "No" -> Save config.

Comment: This fixed it. Strange that after 7 years of using this platform that all of a sudden was on. Thanks Yang!